# Why do some classes in FontAwesome have -o at the end?

Tags: css, font-awesome

Pretty random question here, but just wondered why some classes in FontAwesome (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) have `-o` at the end, such as `fa-hdd-o`.

From an outsider, it seems as though there is no reason for this as there is no other class that might be a variation.

I am asking because I want to see the thinking behind the design decision.

Comment: it may be a different style for the same icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because with the -o they want to say something like outer. For example check `fa-bell` vs `fa-bell-o` and see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think the o stands for an **"outline"** version of the icon. Not all icons have a -o type version of them, by design. This See example of the Font Awesome file icon:

[image: Screenshot example of Font Awesome graphic for file and file-o]

Important to note too that the -o version icons will have a transparent background, so areas not in the outline will show the background color or image they are placed on top of. This aspect gets back to your question @Savvas Nicholas about design and these -o icon types, stylistically they provide a different visual effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the [cheatsheet](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/), you can see the exact difference between the icons having `-o` and the ones which don't. The ones having `-o` usually have more white than black, whereas the ones not having `-o` are rather black.

Answer (score 0):

It stands for "off".

if you take:

```
fa-bell-slash
```

for example when you look at the icon you can sorta tell that its on.

but if you look at:

```
fa-bell-slash-o
```

it looks like the bell is off.